# Is it possible to use one camera in different processes on Raspberry Pi ?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

Is it possible to use one camera in different processes on Raspberry Pi ? 
(for example streaming with motion and rtsp streaming at the same time)

Comment: I am using Raspbian on RPi Zero

Comment: Go through https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=166384&p=1071930